# What solutions for heavy foot dumbbells

Tags: weights, dumbbells, feet

To do fitness (the Desbonnet/Rouhet method) I need foot weights from 8 to 15Kg (17 to 33lbs) per foot.
I only found 2Kg (4.5lbs) weights that you strap around your ankles. I would need to attach at least 4 of them to my ankle which would be little practical and notably more expensive.
Ideally I'm looking for a special shoe onto which I could insert a bar or disks directly.

Comment: Never heard of the Desbonnet/Rouhet method, do you have a link with more information?

Comment: @Chris Desbonnet, basically, is the guy who invented physical fitness 100 years ago. http://bsfpro.fr/index.php?file=Sections&op=article&artid=17

Comment: I wouldn't do that if I were you. If you want to be uber fit, just train like an athlete

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD Go learn what a true athlete is.

Comment: @user2534 I know that a true athlete won't be attaching a 30-lbs weight to their feet *(for whatever exercise training being performed)* . That won't make you run faster, jump higher or perform optimally. Want big thighs? Deadlift and weight-squat! Want endurance? Run/sprint/jog. Want strength? Lift higher weights! Want joint problems later in life? Walk with 30-lbs weights strapped to your ankles.

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD attaching a weight to the feet does nothing but attaching it to the hands does ? how stupid. As stupid as thinking of walking with weights. You know nothing, go waste someone else's time, I didn't ask for your damn opinion.

Comment: @user2534 You cannot compare the strength of the ankles to the elbow. Before you say someone is stupid, why don't you take time to enlighten yourself by googling the potential problems you'll face from such activity. It's okay for you to injure yourself; however, at least, you'll know that it's out of sheer stupidity and not ignorance. Check [Walmart](http://walmart.com) or [Amazon](http://amazon.com) or [Academy](http://academy.com) for the item you're seeking; you should find it on one of those sites.

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD damn right, you can't compare ankles to elbows, you can however compare ankles to the arm's equivalent: wrists, and guess what, ankles are much stronger. There is no potential problems for ankles that there is not for wrists, otherwise muscles weights would not have been invented and used for decades. Why don't YOU check walmart, amazon or academy to answer my question ? huh ? I defy you.

Comment: @user2534 I don't answer questions where the OP is intent on harming themselves. While I can provide a complete explanation, I can see it's not necessary. If you really want to learn, seek other professionals' opinions on your intended goal. If you choose to remain adamant, hopefully, the answer won't originate from this site. Have fun :).

Comment: I already know because I already sought other professionals' opinion, it's called the Desbonnet method. I've been using ankles weights for over 2 months without any side effects, thank you. You don't give the answer, you just give the links to find the stuff to harm oneself, I seeeee

Answer (score 1):

Ankle weights have been heavily used in calisthenics as a substitute to the cumbering dipping belt which disrupts the form of the exercise. Google Matteo Spinozzola and his training regimen with 35kg ankle weights (per leg)

There is no reason to believe ankle weights are dangerous.  It is deemed that they might increase risk of a muscle strain, but muscle strain do not happen because some exercises magically make them happen, muscle strains can happens due to loads being to heavy, fatigue, or simply overtraining. One can get a muscle strain from literally anything.

But I wouldn't go around running with 24kg on my ankles, but I'm certainly not conditioned for that.

If you wanted a cheap alternative I suggest buying a sub belt. The ones used to swim. You can buy many empty belts which are cheap and spend about 20 dollars 4 blocks of lead each weighing 3kg. Loop one weight per ankle and knee and shorten the belts by cutting them if you need too. Some material to cushion might be needed.

[image]